# How to time javascript actions so that they happen at the right order

Tags: javascript, loops, timer

I am trying to figure out how to time this `for` statement so it happens every second or so. What ends up happening is that the `x` prints 5 for all logs because the `for` loop is looping before the Timeout happens. How can I time the loops so every iteration happens after the `setTimeout` finishes.

```js
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {  
  var wait = setTimeout( function() { 
    console.log(x,"x"); 
  }, 800);
}
```

Comment: Set the next timeout in the in the setTimeout code.

Comment: I am not sure i follow you Alex. Could you illustrate this please

Comment: Call setTimeout() once and in the code you specify to run after 800ms call setTimeout() again at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `let x = 0` to make sure `x` is block scoped in the loop and multiply delay times index in order to increment each delay time

```js
for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(x, " x")
  }, (x + 1) * 800);
}
```

Comment: I think this helped me the most. charlietfl is there a specific reason for multiplying the 'x' with the time?

Comment: the loop will complete in milliseconds... I assumed you wanted to increment each delay so they don't all run simultaneously

Comment: Important reading [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers here are of course correct.

But going forward into the future async code is much easier using async / await.

So below is a simple example,.. It initially looks longer, due to utility function delay, but as your program gets larger using async / await will make your code much easier to follow.

Another advantage here too, is only 1 setTimeout is created,.  So potentially more resource friendly.  You could also achieve using 1 setTimeout without async / await but would require chaining the setTimeout's making the code even harder to follow.

```js
// utility function do delay, 
// can be used again..
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

//await can only be called from async function.
//so lets just create run function to get things started.

async function run () {
  for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {  
    await delay(800);
    console.log(x,"x"); 
  }
}

//lets get things started..
run ();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```js
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {  
  (function(n){setTimeout(()=>{console.log(n,"x");},800*n);})(x);
}
```